# Question about tide

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tidal-effect

Let's say a canal is built in the middle of Kansas in the shape of a ring that stretches 100 miles in diameter. The band of water is 100 feet wide and 10 feet deep throughout the entire canal, and the land where the canal is built is flat in every way aside from conforming to the curvature of the earth.
Would a current develop from tidal forces? If so, in what direction would it flow? How rapid would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, tides would not cause a current.  To create a current, the tidal forces need to be asymmetric enough to produce a preferred direction of flow.  In this example, unless the canal were at one Earth's poles, the geometry is such that tidal forces are acting orthogonal to the plane of the canal---effectively canceling itself out once you average over a day.

Additionally, the size scale of the canal is fairly small, decreasing the strength of the tides, compared to (for example) winds, which would dominate on such scales.

Comment: Thanks- I can't upvote your answer due to my low rating, but that was very informative